# Debugging Node.js Apps With Travis ci

Tags: node.js, debugging, travis-ci

My node.js app uses express to listen on port 3000, but when the build succeeds it outputs in the console:

```
Listening to port 3000!
```

That means it succeeded. But there is an issue. When it builds successfully, it doesn't end, and I am not sure how to end it if it is in the travis CI. Travis waits 10 minutes, then kills the process causing the build to fail.

Basically what I am trying to ask is how would I know it is in the travis ci, and what can i do if the build succeeds to end the task? Or is there a certain setting I could use to end the task when it succeeds?

I am completely new to this, and I couldn't find anything on google for it.

Comment: Instead of having Travis run your entire application, you should create some tests that are run to verify the key components of your application.

Comment: Currently my configuration only runs the server.js cause that is the only thing that needs to be ran, the issue is that the build fails cause it goes on longer than 10 minutes, which causes the build to fail. I need to prevent that.

Comment: Your `server.js` file is running as intended; it's starting a server and keeping the server open so that it can accept requests.  Travis is designed to run specially written test files to verify the key components of your application - you should write some tests and have Travis run those instead of your main app.

Comment: `command-that-runs-your-server &`

Comment: @набиячлэвэли With the `&` at the end it always succeeds. I need it to fail as well if there are errors.

Comment: @CaseyPrimozic the test only involves running the server.js file, there are no arguments.